# Update WooCommerce product and variant stock from csv

Tags: php, csv, woocommerce, product, variant

Following [Update WooCommerce product stock from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145694)

How do I modify the code if the SKU is not a product SKU but a product variant SKU? So how do I update the stock of a product variant if I only know the SKU of the variant? There is no wc_get_variant_id_by_sku...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datastore function checks for both Product and Product variation in the function as shown below.

```
/**
 * Return product ID based on SKU.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @param string $sku Product SKU.
 * @return int
 */
public function get_product_id_by_sku( $sku ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // phpcs:ignore WordPress.VIP.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery
    $id = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "
            SELECT posts.ID
            FROM {$wpdb->posts} as posts
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup} AS lookup ON posts.ID = lookup.product_id
            WHERE
            posts.post_type IN ( 'product', 'product_variation' )
            AND posts.post_status != 'trash'
            AND lookup.sku = %s
            LIMIT 1
            ",
            $sku
        )
    );

    return (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_product_id_by_sku', $id, $sku );
}
```

So the function can be used for variations as well.

`wc_get_product_id_by_sku($sku);` - It will return the variation ID if a variation SKU is passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the problem was in the next line in my PHP. I used $product = new WC_Product( $product_id ) with the ID instead of $product = WC_Get_Product( $product_id ) and this droped an error.